# Rewriting URL in jsf

Tags: jsf

I am newbie to the jsf.

Currently my application URL looks like

```
http://localhost/practice/pages/page1.xhtml
```

Question is how I rewrite the URL to make it like

```
http://localhost/practice/page1.xhtml
```

Basically I want to hide pages.

Comment: Thus ... Your `FacesServlet` is mapped on an URL pattern of `/pages/*` instead of `*.xhtml`? Why exactly do you have `/pages` there in first place?

Comment: Actually I have a h:commandButton whose action attribute points to page1.xhtml which resides in the page directory. I have no such mapping like /pages/* .

Comment: Why do you have a `/pages` directory in first place then? Wouldn't it be obvious that when you remove that directory and put the files in the root folder, that you then don't need to specify that directory in URLs anymore?

Comment: It is like I have all the .xhtml files under pages directory. Do you want me to put all the individual .xhtml files under root directory? Is there no other way out where out where pages will not be visible in  url. I remember with the same kind of directory structure in struts the url will always be like /webapp/actionName.

Comment: Me? *You* want to get rid of `/pages` in URL. I was merely pointing out that it's caused by using a `/pages` folder and that you can get rid of the `/pages` in URL by getting rid of `/pages` folder.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [prettyfaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/)
 for rewriting url in jsf.it is open source and easy for use

Comment: Can it be possible with mojarra?

Comment: @Rajat can you give it a try first?